# my joda time zone messup

Tags: java, jodatime

guys.

im newbie in using joda time api. so here is my question. Ive app server deploy somewhere in the western region and the date fixed to the particular time , Fri Feb  6 08:50:54 UTC 2015.

however, i try to use joda time zone to change the timezone to my country. it didnt worked out. i have run out of ideas. below is my code :

```
java.util.Date dateIn = new java.util.Date(); 
            DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( dateIn, DateTimeZone.UTC );
            System.out.println("date time utc : " + dateTimeUtc);


            DateTimeZone timeZoneLos_Angeles = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ); // Adjust time zone to United States.
            DateTime dateTimeLos_Angeles = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneLos_Angeles );
            System.out.println("los angeles date time : " + dateTimeLos_Angeles.toDate());

            DateTimeZone timeZoneMalaysia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Singapore" );
            DateTime dateTimeKL = dateTimeLos_Angeles.withZone( timeZoneMalaysia );
            System.out.println("KL date time : " + dateTimeKL.toDate());

            java.util.Date newDate = dateTimeKL.toDate();

            System.out.println("after convert to j.u.Date : " + newDate);
```

the output:

```
date time utc : 2015-02-06T08:58:29.127Z
los angeles date time : Fri Feb 06 16:58:29 SGT 2015
KL date time : Fri Feb 06 16:58:29 SGT 2015
after convert to j.u.Date : Fri Feb 06 16:58:29 SGT 2015
```

i dont know what's going on now. joda time is using my local machine time. 
can u guys explain what is happening here? am i accessing joda time in wrong way. or is it my mistake?

Comment: Do not use DateTime.toDate() method.

Comment: @Mufanu, why? i seen a lot from this forum said to use this DateTime.toDate() method to convert to java.uti.Date.

Comment: @ Keluang Yang Ko Kenal, this method create new object java.util.Date. As @JB Nizet said java.util.Date uses the default timezone of the JVM

Comment: @Mufanu - thx for clear information.

Answer (score 3):

A `java.util.Date` is basically the same thing as a joda-time `Instant`: an instant on the universal time scale. It doesn't have any time zone. It's just a number of milliseconds wrapped into an object. So when you call `toString()` on a `java.util.Date` instance, this object tries to make this number of millisecond readable to you, and transforms it to a readable date using **the default timezone of the JVM**: SGT in this case.

If you want to see a date in a given timezone, then print the `DateTime` instance itself (which contains an instant *and* a time zone) instead of transforming it to a Date (which loses the timezone information), or use a `SimpleDateFormat` configured with the timezone you want to display the `java.util.Date` to a string in the wanted time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Joda Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still providing a simple API. Converting a Joda DateTime object from one timezone to another is pretty easy and saves you quite a number of lines of code. See method below.

```
public static Date convertJodaTimezone(LocalDateTime date, String srcTz, String destTz) {
    DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(srcTz));
    DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(destTz));
    return dstDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toDateTime().toDate();
}
```

Since Joda Time has its own class for storing Date and Calendar objects, the DateTime class has its own toDate() method for converting it to a java.util.Date.

For further example check this [link](http://abstractlayers.com/2013/12/15/joda-time-for-timezones/)

Answer (score 0):

I reused your code and did some changes. The commented lines were the previous implementation so that you can compare the difference with the new implementation.

```
    Date dateIn = new Date(); 
    DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( dateIn, DateTimeZone.UTC );
    System.out.println("date time utc : " + dateTimeUtc);

    DateTimeZone timeZoneLos_Angeles = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ); // Adjust time zone to United States.
    //DateTime dateTimeLos_Angeles = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneLos_Angeles );
    DateTime dateTimeLos_Angeles = dateTimeUtc.withZone(timeZoneLos_Angeles);
    //System.out.println("los angeles date time : " + dateTimeLos_Angeles.toDate());
    System.out.println("los angeles date time : " + dateTimeLos_Angeles.toLocalDateTime().toDate());

    DateTimeZone timeZoneMalaysia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Singapore" );
    DateTime dateTimeKL = dateTimeUtc.withZone(timeZoneMalaysia);
    //System.out.println("KL date time : " + dateTimeKL.toDate());
    System.out.println("KL date time : " + dateTimeKL.toLocalDateTime().toDate());

    //Date newDate = dateTimeKL.toDate();
    Date newDate = dateTimeKL.toLocalDateTime().toDate();

    System.out.println("after convert to j.u.Date : " + newDate);
```

I hope this one works for you. If you can optimize this code further then great. Cheers!